# Symmetric matrix - Langrange Multiplier

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix. Let $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \|x\|_2=1\}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the $2$-norm $\|x\|_2=\sqrt{\langle{x,x}\rangle}$ where $\langle{x,y}\rangle=y^Tx=x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n$ is the scalar product. Define $f(v)=v^TAv=\langle{v,Av}\rangle$ for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a=\inf\{f(v) \mid v \in S\}$.

(a) Find the frechet derivative of $f$ at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

(b) Show that there is $v \in S$ s.t. $f(v)=a$.

(c) Take the vector in (b). Using the Lagrange Multiplier Theorem to show that $Av=av$.

(d) Using the above show that $a$ is equal to the  smallest real eigenvalue of $A$.

(a) No idea how to find derivatives using norms. Could I get a hint?

(b) This would show the infimum is attained. Not really sure how to show it formally but would it be something similar to the extreme value theorem.

(c) I think I need the answer in part (a) for this.

Comment: A small typesetting correction: One should write $\mathbb R^n$, not $\mathbb{R^n}$, i.e. the $n$ should not be within the \mathbb{}. I changed it. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $u, v$ are vectors in $R^n$
since $f(u) = \sum{i, j} u_iA_{ij}u_j$,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_k} = \sum_{j}A_{kj}u_j + \sum_{i} u_iA_{ik}  = \sum_{j}A_{kj}u_j + \sum_{j}u_jA_{jk} = \sum_{j}A_{kj}u_j + \sum_{j}A_{kj}U_j = 2\sum_{j}A_{kj}u_j$$

Write as vector
$$Df(u) = 2Au$$
a. $Df(u) = 2 Au$ since $A$ is symmetry.

b. f(v) is continuous on the compact set S. So it has a minimum on S. Let $v \in S$ be the minimal, adn $a = f(v) = v^TAv.

c $L(u) = f(u) + c ( 1 - |u|^2)$ using Lagrange multipler method, then
$$DL(u) = Df(u) - 2c u = 2Au - 2cu $$
From $DL(v) = 0$, we have $Av = c v$.
Multiple it by v, we have $a = v^tAv = c vTv = c$.
So $Av = a v$

d. A is symmetric, so $A = P^TDP$, P is orthogonal, where $D = diag(\lambda_1, ... \lambda_n)$, let $w = Pu = (w_j)$, $||w||^2 = ||Pu||^2 = (Pu, Pu) = u^TP^pPu = u^Tu = 1$ so
$$f(u) = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i w_i^2 \ge min\{\lambda_j\} \sum_{j=1}^n w_j^2 = min\{\lambda_j\}$$

so $a \ge min\{\lambda_j\}$. Let w be the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue, we see $f(w) = min\{\lambda_j\}$, so $a = min\{\lambda_j\}$

Comment: (a) How do I formally show the derivative is that?

Comment: @Calvin, just differentiate. I showed you in the asnwer.

Comment: Thanks, what about part (d)?

Comment: @Calvin, d needs more matrix knowledge. I added.

Comment: @runaround How did you $L(u)=...$ for (c) and what is the variable $c$?

For (d) why is $A=P^TDP$?

Comment: @Polp, the c in (c) is a unknown costant in Lagrange multipler method, which is to be determined by solving equations of $DL(u) = 0$.